# shell script to replace all function calls with another call

Tags: regex, shell, replace, grep

I have modified a function lets say

`foo(int a, char b);`   into    `foo(int a, char b, float new_var);`

The old function foo was is called from many places in the existing source code, I want to replace all occurence of `foo(some_a, some_b);`   with   `foo(some_a, some_b, 0);` using a script (manual editing is laborius).

I tried to do the same with `grep 's/old/new/g' file`   but the problem is with using regex to match the parameters, and insert the same into replacement text.

PS: `a` & `b` are either valid C variable names OR valid constant values for their types.

Comment: this doesn't make sense. what's the value of `new_var`?

Comment: sorry ... its always 0 expect in a couple of places .. will update the question

Comment: it's impossible to do a dumb search&replace unless a and b are *always* really simple, which can be described by a regex.

Comment: a & b are C variable names or constant values both of which can be described by regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should make it:

```
sed -i.bak -r "s/foo\(\s*([0-9]*)\s*,\s*(([0-Z]|'[0-Z]'))\s*\)/foo(\1, \2, 0)/g" file
```

Note the `-i.bak` stands for "replace inplace" and create a backup of the original file in `file.bak`.

- `foo\(\s*([0-9]*)\s*,\s*(([0-Z]|'[0-Z]'))\s*\)` looks for something like `foo(` + `spaces` + `digits` + `spaces` + `,` + `spaces` + [ `'character'` or `character` ] + `spaces` + `)`. And replaces with `foo(` + `digits` + `,` + `character` + `0` + `)`.

#### Example

```
$ cat a
hello foo(23, h);
this is another foo(23, bye);
this is another foo(23, 'b');
and we are calling to_foo(23, 'b'); here
foo(23, 'b'); here

$ sed -i.bak -r "s/foo\(\s*([0-9]*)\s*,\s*(([0-Z]|'[0-Z]'))\s*\)/foo(\1, \2, 0)/g" a
$ cat a
hello foo(23, h, 0);
this is another foo(23, bye);
this is another foo(23, 'b', 0);
and we are calling to_foo(23, 'b', 0); here
foo(23, 'b', 0); here
```

Comment: I believe the function is **called**. Not declared.

Comment: I don't see any problems with a downvote. It's your responsbility to assess that what they want makes sense.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I do see a problem. If your behaviour has the extended one, I guess nobody would answer. In my case, I prefer to leave a comment.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes it does.

Comment: @fedorqui: do you? I actually decided not to answer, left a comment, and *waited for* a response.

Comment: @fedorqui: shouldn't the regex for parameter 1 and 2 account for both variable names and possible constant valuesi.e foo( 'regex const|var_name' ,'regex const|var_name') rather than foo (regex const, regex var_name

Comment: thank you. what he meant is that you're assuming the first parameter is a number literal and the second is a variable.

Comment: Well @Deepthought the definition of the function is `foo(int a, char b)`, so first one should be a number while the second a char. So in fact I should change to `[0-9]*` in first case and `[0-Z]` in the second.

Comment: character literals look like this: `'A'`.

Comment: Uhms, missed that option @KarolyHorvath  Added a condition to check either `character` or `'character'`.

Comment: Well @Deepthought now I think it is completely complete :)

Answer (score 2):

Since we are working with C code, we don't need to worry about function overloading issue.

Under the assumption of **simple variable names** and **constant** being passed into function call, and that the code was compilable before the change in function prototype:

1. Search with `foo(\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\))` and replace with `foo(\1,\2,0)`.

   There are a few caveats, though:

   - The `char` field should not contain `','`. It will not be replaced if it does.
   - The `char` field should not contain `)`. It **will** cause bad replacement.
   - There is no function whose name ends with `foo`. The replacement may make a mess out of your code if there is.
2. Search with `\(foo([^)]+\)` and replace with `\1,0` (Thanks to [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman))

   There are a few caveats, though:

   - Both `int` and `char` field should not contain `)`. It **will** cause bad replacement.
   - There is no function whose name ends with `foo`. Similarly, the replacement may make a mess out of your code.

Comment: @fedorqui: `[^,]` should take care of spaces (or does it?)

Comment: Fair enough, you are completely right. Removing my comment and +1, now I see my approach is a little complicated

Comment: I would think replacing `\(foo([^)]\+\)` with `\1,0` would be easier.

Comment: @glennjackman: It is less "safe", though. If the call to `foo` contains `)`, things will be replaced sporadically.

Comment: That is a recursive rat hole: `foo(bar(x,y),baz(w,v))` contains both extra parentheses and commas. In hindsight, this is something that may require an IDE to do properly, something that understands both the syntax and semantics of the language..

Comment: @glennjackman: The OP already states "variable and constant", so that case won't happen. For your case, given `foo(x, ')')`, it will do a replacement, which will mess the code up.

Comment: good point. However, in that case, your regex will result in `foo(x,',0)')` inserting the ",0" too early.